# jQuery flot plugin, plots and labels order

Tags: jquery, flot

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

By default plots and labels display in order, which i defined them

```
$.plot($("#chart"),
                        plotData
                    ,
                    {
                        series:{
                        lines:{ show:true },
                        points:{ show:true }
                        },
                        grid:{ hoverable:true, clickable:true },
                        yaxis:{ min:0, max:data.maxYaxisValue, tickDecimals:0},
                        xaxis:{ tickFormatter:tickFormatter}
                    }
                );
```

Where plotdata is a array, with structure:

```
var plotData = [
 {data: statData1,  color: plotColor1, label: label1},
 {data: statData2,  color: plotColor2, label: label2},
 {data: statData3,  color: plotColor3, label: label3}
];
```

I want show plots in one order, labels in other:

plots:

plot1 plot2 plot3

legend table:

plot3 plot1 plot2

I have only one idea: change order in legend table by script, i don't see option here for this

```
  if ($('#chart div.legend table tr').length > 1) {
                var $tableRow = $('#chart div.legend table tr:last');
                $tableRow.insertBefore($('#chart div.legend table tr:first'));
            }
```

Exist a better way for do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flot master branch on [Github](https://github.com/flot/flot) supports sorting legend labels independently of their series.

It was just added about a week ago, so if you're already using the master branch, you may just need to update.  If you're using 0.7, you can either switch to the master branch, if you're okay with it being much less stable, or find those specific commits in the history and apply them to your copy manually.

Comment: This great, thank you, but sorted option is function for sort method.
I compltete my example, and how you see now labels order is no descending or ascending, is a arbitrary order. I just want put last element of array put to the first position

Comment: You can still do it; it's just a little more work.  Your sort function accepts series a & b.  Iterate over the original plotData array and compare by label to find the index of both series in plotData.  Then if aIndex == plotData.length - 1, return -1 to sort it behind everything else, otherwise return aIndex - bIndex to keep the rest sorted regularly by index.

Comment: Thanks, but in the future sort function is not best way =)
LabelOrder option in series data would be more convenient =)